# Create a package in Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am using Modelica in my work, where I have modeled a system that contains many models. I want to make it simple to use by creating a package using " within" so this package contains all the models. What I want is to open the package instead of opening many models, which takes time.

Comment: https://mbe.modelica.university/components/packages/organizing/

Comment: You could create a `package.mo` file, which contains the information to load this package, There are two good examples: https://marcobonvini.com/modelica/2017/01/05/modelica-in-action-packages.html    https://www.modelica.org/events/Conference2003/Modelica03-AdvancedTutorial.pdf  If you wanna build models related to a thermo-fluid system, MSL. Fluid is great as a reference.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing everything by hand, I suggest to create your packages with a Modelica tool (OpenModelica, Dymola, SimulationX, ...).

The tool will automatically create the folder structure and the `within` lines in the .mo files for you. Doing it manually is not much fun.

You could e.g. use OMEdit (part of OpenModelica) to create your package structure as follow:

- create your top-level package via *File > New Modelica Class*
- insert sub-models and sub-packages in existing packages via *right-click > New Modelica Class*

Answer (score 0):

According to this website http://omwebbook.openmodelica.org/
**A package is simply a container or namespace for names of classes, functions, constants, and other allowed definitions. The package name is prefixed to all definitions in the package using standard dot notation. An import language construct is provided for Modelica packages.**

the package can help us to gather components that build the main model together in same place inside it , just by clicking on the package you open all your components inside it.
to open a package in Modelica we follow the follwing instructions:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

After creationg the package you will get a folder with the package name in the place that you chosed to saved it in it , when you open the folder you click on package in order to open your package .
hope this can be helpfull